# iOS: is it possible to change the hyperlink text to a different name yet still redirects you to the same site?

Tags: ios, objective-c, hyperlink

For example, the code below creates a hyperlink to google.com. However, I need the text to say "click here" and still go to google.com. I must have this in text form (no buttons or any other object).

Edit : myView is a textView. Sorry, forgot to add that in.

```
myView.text = @"http://google.com";
myView.editable = NO;
```

Comment: What is the type of `myView`? `UITextView`?

Comment: I apologize, but yes it is a textview.

Comment: But why not to use `UIButton`?

Comment: I just want to see if there is a more convenient way of doing this. I realize a UIButton could work.

Comment: If you need only one link, `UITextView` is overkill here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You need to use an attributed string

```
NSMutableAttributedString * str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"click here"];
[str addAttribute: NSLinkAttributeName value: @"http://www.google.com" range: NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
myView.attributedText = str;
```

Also be sure that you conform to the UITextViewDelegate and implement this method

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)url inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
{
     return YES;
}
```

One caveat - it looks like NSLinkAttributeName prefers an NSURL but the docs say it should also work with a string.